# Why is the mesh of the crop top doing this ingame (vrchat)

Tags: mesh, unity

So i have added a crop top with a blendshape to my avatar and in atleast blender and unity it looks perfectly fine but when i bring it ingame it breaks... pictures below:
First shows the broken part and second shows a picture from unity.
https://gyazo.com/02b4cda4c6cea40eaf947a90462ebb50
https://gyazo.com/1a2810c67c4769349114270c71e3d782
Anybody knows how to fix this? would be so happy if i can fix this rather than removing it completly..

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So im asking why the crop top is breaking like that, like why it looks fine in blender/unity but ingame (vrchat) the mesh under the arm just breaks

Comment: This problem has now been solved